# convert image to bitmap (Android)

Tags: android, bitmap

If I have a view object with a canvas that draws lines how do I convert the image to a bitmap and then save it as a PNG? I want to do this in the saveCanvasImage() method. In the code below I'm assuming I have to use getDrawingCache somehow with the tv object. I don't get what I've read about this at all. (Assume the view object exists even though that doesn't happen until a command button is pressed).

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_save:
            saveCanvasImage();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_sign:
            openTEV();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void saveCanvasImage() {

    Log.d("key1","save test");

}

public void openTEV() {

    Log.d("key2","set content view");
    MyTouchEventView tv = new MyTouchEventView(this);
    setContentView(tv);
    addContentView(tv.btnReset, tv.params);

}
```

}

MyTouchEventView.java:

```
public class MyTouchEventView extends View {

private Paint paint = new Paint();
private Path path = new Path();

public Button btnReset;
public LayoutParams params;

public MyTouchEventView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10f);

    btnReset = new Button(context);
    btnReset.setText("Clear Screen");

    params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    btnReset.setLayoutParams(params);

    btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // resets the screen
            path.reset();

            // Calls the onDraw() method
            postInvalidate();

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    // Gives you x and y coordinates on the Event.
    float pointX = event.getX();
    float pointY = event.getY();

    // Checks for the event that occurs
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        path.moveTo(pointX, pointY);
        return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        path.lineTo(pointX, pointY);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        //;
        break;
    default:
        return false;
    }

    // Schedules a repaint.
    // Force a view to draw.
    postInvalidate();
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Where is the code where you are drawing to the canvas?

Comment: Hi there. I've add the code for the view class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each View has a bitmap in which the view drawing is cached. Have a read about [View.getDrawingCache()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache%28%29) in the android reference docs.

Note: you will also need to set [View.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setDrawingCacheEnabled%28boolean%29)

---

To answer your comment, at the moment you create a `MyTouchEventView` called `tv` locally in the method `openTEV()`.

To make `tv` acessable in other methods, you could instead make it a class level object. Declare it at the top of your MainActivity class.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Class Variables
    private MyTouchEventView tv;
    ...
```

Then you can change `openTEV()` to:

```
public void openTEV() {

    Log.d("key2","set content view");
    tv = new MyTouchEventView(this);
    setContentView(tv);
    addContentView(tv.btnReset, tv.params);
}
```

Then you can also access it it elsewhere in the MainActivity class. For example:

```
public void saveCanvasImage() {

    ...
    tv.getDrawingCache();  // We can access tv because it was created at the class level
    ...

    Log.d("key1","save test");

}
```

Comment: What I'm really falling down with in learning Java is how to correctly make objects and methods communicate with each other. I'm assuming that if the cache is enabled then I'll have the line tv.getDrawingCache() somewhere. I can't put that in saveCanvasImage though, it will be invalid. So would I have to pass the tv object in as a parameter (which I'm not sure how to do)? I'm wondering if this is something so basic most Java programmers don't bother mentioning it.